# Search on Trello does not return any results when viewing public boards

Tags: trello

When I search for something on the Trello Development board, why does the search box return no results?

It seems like the search function only returns matches to members and items from my own boards that match the search query.

So how do I search the Trello Development board, or within any other public boards?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Searching a public Trello board]

[We at Trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/9179/rich-armstrong) try to make the top search bar only return things that are "yours".  To search a particular board you're looking at, it's better to use **Search and Filter Cards**.